# By using PHP Codeigniter How To Count children for binary tree

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, binary-tree

I have built a binary tree using PHP Codeigniter but i want function that can

1. Count the left child and right child for every parent.
2. print a message when balanced happened on the tree like if the number of the

   left children equal to right children send message (balanced happened ) .

   MY tree Parent in my database = mdi , child = id .

   Thanks in advance.

Comment: take a look here this may help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16340374/general-tree-traversalinfinite-in-breadth-first-search-manner?rq=1

Comment: Need more help . thanks man